# MySQL запрос по подсчету с исключающим условием

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть база *cdr*
*id* |  *disp*
1  |    NO ANSWER
1  |   ANSWERED
2  |    BUSY
1  |    NO ANSWER
2  |    NO ANSWER
2  |    FAILED

Хочу подсчитать количество уникальных id, которые принимают значение 'NO ANSWER', но при этому никогда не принимают значение 'ANSWERED'.
В данном случае запрос должен подсчитать только id=2 и в результате вывести в ответе 1 (нашел один id, соответствующий условиям)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)  FROM cdr WHERE disp = 'NO ANSWER' AND disposition != 'ANSWERED';
```

не работает.

Comment: таблицу бы разить на две, не имеет смысла во всех строках хранить ANSWERED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале нужно выбрать все id, которые не принимают значение `ANSWERED`, а потом отфильтровать их по значению `NO ANSWER`. Один из вариантов решения такой

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM
  cdr
WHERE
  disp = 'NO ANSWER' AND 
  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM cdr WHERE disp = 'ANSWERED');
```

Comment: Сказалось мое незнание синтаксиса - обычно с MYSQL не работаю.
Ваш запрос сделал то, что надо. Заодно подсказал, как решить еще несколько задач.

Comment: данный синтаксис является стандартным для ANSI SQL так что работать будет в любой СУБД поддерживающей его в т.ч. sql server, access, oracle и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Дак и пишите запрос именно так каким он описывается в тексте. Выберите те строки, которые принимают значения `no answer` а затем исключите из них те, которые когда-либо принимают значение `answered`.

```
 SELECT count(distinct id) 
 FROM data
 WHERE disp = 'NO ANSWER' 
     AND id not in (
          SELECT distinct id 
          FROM data 
          WHERE disp = 'ANSWERED'
     )
```